# How to enter result in excel file in selenium using java

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I already done with written the code of read input data from excel,now i want to write PASS,FAIL result to particular test case in excel but i don't have any idea to how to write proper code. so can u somebody give me some example.

Please Help me.
 This is my code.

```
            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            WebDriver driver=null;
             Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           //  prompt for the URL
            System.out.print("Enter your URL: ");
            // get their input as a String
            String URL = scanner.next();
            //System.out.println( URL );

            final FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
          driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
           driver.get(URL);
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          driver.manage().window().maximize();
            //read data from excel
                try {   
                  FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Deepa\\Desktop\\AMC test cases1.xls")); 
                   HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
                   HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("login page");

                   WebElement login=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[data-target='#login-box']"));
                     login.click();
                     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //For Email ID 
       driver.findElement(By.id(sheet.getRow(1).getCell(1).getStringCellValue())).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(1).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());

    //FOR Password 

    driver.findElement(By.id(sheet.getRow(2).getCell(1).getStringCellValue())).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(2).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());

     //For Submit the form 
      driver.findElement(By.id(sheet.getRow(3).getCell(1).getStringCellValue())).click();

                   file.close();
//Else

             } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
                     fnfe.printStackTrace();
             } catch (IOException ioe) {
                      ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use POI jars Use `getXLcellValue` function to get the value in excel Use `setXLCellValue` function to set the value in excel

Parameters :-

- xlpath -> Location of your Excel file
- sheetName -> Sheet name in your Excel File
- rowNum and cellNum -> Row and column number where your data is
  present

  ```
  public String getXLcellValue(String xlpath, String sheetName, int rowNum, int cellNum)

    {
       try{
              FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(xlpath);
          Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fis);

      Log.info("Get the value from the cell(getXLcellValue)");

          return wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(rowNum).getCell(cellNum).getStringCellValue();
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
      Log.info("Error in getXLcellValue ="+ ex.getMessage());
  }
   return "";
  }


     //set the value of the cell present in specific sheet

      void setXLCellValue(String xlpath,String sheetName,int rowNum,int cellNum, String input)
     {

       try{
           FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(xlpath);

           Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fis);

      wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(rowNum).createCell(cellNum).setCellValue(input);

      FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(xlpath);

      wb.write(fos);

      fos.close();

      Log.info("Set the value in cell(setXLCellValue)");

  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
      Log.info("Error in setXLCellValue ="+ ex.getMessage());
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks but i want to return pass fail result on the basis of error class that  gets bind to the input field if error exists.

Comment: If error is occur then result will be FAIL otherwise result is PASS.